# What is the meaning to be + can

Tags: grammar

I have seen a few sentences that did not make sense (at least for me)

1) Brands that know who they **are can** be fearless

2) They are not quite the same thing, but the perception that they **are can** sometimes lead to some confusion.

3) They **are can't** wait to meet new visitors

I got the meaning, but I did not understand the sentence composition.

Comment: 1 and 2 are grammatical. 3 is not.  In 1 and 2 “are can” is not parsed together.  in 1, There are brands that know who they are.  Those brands can be fearless.  Similarly in 2

Comment: "are can" is not a constituent; you've misparsed it.

Comment: If you encounter someone using the phrase "are can saw" in a sentence, the person may be from Little Rock.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such collocation.

The first two examples include embedded clauses "who they are" and "the perception that they are".

The third is a mistake, and is not grammatical/